# Is the daughter of Brahma in shatpatha brahmana Sandhya the nymph or saraswati?

Tags: puranas, brahma, saraswati, shatapatha-brahmana, brahmanas

The story of Brahma lusting after his daughter due to arrow struck by kama deva is present in shatpatha brahmana, my question is, is the daughter called Sandhya or saraswati, because there is differing legend in some puranas some say Brahma lusted after her nymph daughter sandhya not saraswati.

If there is difference between the Vedic and puranic version, Vedic version has to be accepted, if I'm correct.